# RequireJS and Bootstrap (Navbar) Dropdowns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, requirejs, durandal

I recently integrated **Durandal** into my project and it's working quite well. However, I did have an issue with the bootstrap dropdowns in the **navbar** not working. I solved this by adding the following JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[data-toggle=dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

I am curious as to whether this is the expected fix or if I'm just hacking my way through this and ignoring an underlying issue. Prior to integrating **Durandal**, the **navbar** was working perfectly well without this code, same as I have done many times in many other projects before this.

Answer (score 0):

The Durandal way to do this is to place your widget setup code (Bootstrap jQuery in this case) within the `attached` or `compositionComplete` hooks of your module. The logic being that Durandal has no idea what additional widgets you are using in your UI, so, you have to tell it. These hooks are conveniently provided within the framework just for this purpose. Once Durandal has completed binding and attaching the view, run some custom code to pretty up the UI. It's the same sort of concept that `$(document).ready()` does for jQuery.

```
// this code assumes that jQuery is loaded globally
define(function(require){
  var vm = {
    //...
  };

  vm.attached = function() {
    $('a[data-toggle=dropdown').dropdown();
  };

  return vm;
});
```

[Reference: Interacting with the DOM](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM.html)